# Looking for review of my attempts involving line integral of vector functions

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

Hello I do not have much experience in these problems so I am looking to see if anyone can help me to look over the following;

For the vector function $F(2xy,x^2+2yz,y^2+1)$ determine if $\nabla \psi=F$ has a solution and determine $\phi$ if possible and then calculate the line integral from the origin to $(1,1,1)$ along $x=y=z$ and then along the curve $y=x^2,z=x^3$. I included my answer and I also would appreciate if someone could check if my final numerical answers are correct or if I made mistakes.

My thoughts:

Through the process of taking partial derivatives and doing reverse integration, I found that $$\psi(x,y,z)=x^2y+y^2z+z$$

I believe that this tells me that the vector field is conservative, all though I do not really have a deep understanding of what that can tell us.

For the next part,

I know that the line integral for a vector function is given as $$\int_{C} F(r(t)) \bullet r'(t) dt$$

We have $$F(x,y,z)=(2xy)i+(x^2+2yz)j+(y^2+1)k$$

I am not sure what is meant by along $x=y=z$,

does this just mean by the line segment given by the line segment

$r(t)=(t,t,t)$ , $0 \le t \le 1$

So $$F(r(t))=(2t^2)i+(3t^2)j+(t^2+1)k$$

and dotted with (1,1,1)

So we would just need to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} 6t^2+1=3$

For $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$ via $y=x^2$ and $z=x^3$ I am less sure.

It seems that $x$ is the parameter. But I dont know how I can find the $r(t)$. That is where I am at so far. Would it just be that $r(t)=(t,t^2,t^3)$ and so $r'(t)=(1,2t,3t^2)$ and thus would come down to evaluating the $\int_{0}^{1} 2t^3+2t^3+4t^6+3t^6+3t^2 dt=\int_{0}^{1} 3t^2+4t^3+7t^6 dt=3$

To make sure I understand the method, I also want to try evaluating over the same paths but with $$F(x,y,z)=(2xyz^3)i+(-x^2z^3-2y)j+(3x^2+yz^2)k$$

I used the same method but it seems like my answer is not the same as other people who have checked it so I must be making a mistake.  I wont include all the work but here is what I tried.

Over $x=y=z$  $F(r(t))=(2t^5)i+(-t^2-2t)j+(3t^5)k$

$F(r(t)) \bullet r'(t)= 4t^5-2t$. evaluating that integral from $0$ to $1$ comes as $\frac{-1}{3}$

over the other path

I calculated $F(r(t))=(2t^{12})i+(-t^{11}-2t^2)j+(3t^{10})k$

and $F(r(t)) \bullet r'(t)= 11t^{12}-2t^{11}-4t^{3}$ 
which I evaluated to be $\frac{-25}{78}$

Does anyone see where I could have gone wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For the non-conservative vector field, your calculations of $F(r(t))$ are wrong. For the first path, $F(r(t)) = <2t^5, -t^5 -2t, 3t^2 + t^3>$. For the second path, $F(r(t)) = <2t^{12}, -t^11 - 2t^2, 3t^2 + t^8>$.

Comment: Oh wow , I had written on my page 3x^2yz^2 instead of the addition sign, this should fix it

Comment: For first path, I get 5/12 and for second, -139/55 . Is it still wrong?

Comment: WolframAlpha agrees with your first answer and disagrees with your second answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+-4t%5E3+%2B+9t%5E4+%2B+3t%5E10+from+0+to+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've found a potential function $\psi$ for your vector field $F$. So you know it's a conservative field. Now you can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals to calculate both of those line integrals without doing any actual integration.

$$ \int_C \mathbf{F \cdot dr} = \psi(b) - \psi(a) $$

where $a$ is the starting point of the path $C$ and $b$ is the endpoint of the path $C$.

Since the field is conservative, the actual path taken from the origin to $(1,1,1)$ doesn't matter - both line integrals have the same value.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned however, that I want to understand the paths as well because I want to evauluate some other vector functions over it as well, and some are not conservative

Comment: @Quality Your calculation of the line integrals for the first vector field also looks correct to me.

Comment: For both examples ? Even with the non conservative field ?

Comment: @Quality
I didn't get the same answers for the non conservative fields, but I may have made a mistake. I think WolframAlpha has a line integral calculator online, so consider consulting it.

Comment: Thanks I have tried to find it but I didnt have luck. I guess I must have made some mistakes in my calculations

Comment: @Quality You can use WolframAlpha to check the integral after the dot product step. It's better than nothing :)

Comment: I updated the post with my work to see if anyone could see where I went wrong